# how to add key shortcut to my app's button?

Tags: android

I created a small Android app, with a few button on the layout. The button are of course clickable, but I also want the user to be able to trigger the button if he/she have a physical keyboard connected, or use a Chromebook, or use a feature-phone (the one with a physical num pad).
For example, I want this button :

```
<Button
 android:id="@+id/bRepeat"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:layout_weight="1"
 android:text="Repeat"
 android:textAllCaps="false" />
```

This button must be trigger when the user click on it, or also when he press `ALT + R` for example (or `R` only).

I did not find an attribute related to shortcut, or using "&R" in the button label, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way, in Android Studio (2020.3.1) to visually add a key handler event. I had to do it by code.

In the `MainActivity`, add an `onKeyDown` method that will receive all key pressed on the activity. Then on this method, filter the key you want to propagate to the existing button.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
     switch(keyCode)   {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_R: 
          bRepeatClick((Button)findViewById(R.id.bRepeat));
          break;
     }
     return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```